# Openlayers overview map spins in the wrong direction

Tags: openlayers

Using OpenLayers ver 6.1 the rotate map icon and overview map boundary box spin in opposite directions. The map boundary box spins in the overview map, which is an improvement from ver 5, but in the wrong direction.

Comment: If it spun in the same direction the box wouldn't show the area covered by the main map. If you rotate the example map about 45 degrees so it stretches from northern Spain to central Germany you can see the effect https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h2iH.jpg

Comment: You are exactly right, my apologies.  Thanks.